# Relationship between Betti numbers $b_i(M;\mathbb{Q})$ and the dimension of rational homotopy $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\pi_i(M)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: homotopy-theory, betti-numbers, rational-homotopy-theory

What is the relationship between the Betti numbers $b_i(M;\mathbb{Q})=rkH_i(M;\mathbb{Q})$ of a Riemannian manifold $M$ and the dimension of rational homotopy $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}\pi_i(M)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ (if there is any)?

[Cross posting on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306775/relationship-between-the-betti-numbers-b-im-mathbbq-and-the-dimension-of)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The topic was already mentioned in the linked MO thread, but I'd suggest looking at minimal models first. For example, that approach allows you to compute the rational homotopy groups of $S^n$ without too much difficulty. Try the book by Felix, Halperin, and Thomas (which, as an added bonus, contains a proof of the almost folklore result that Lie groups have $\pi_2 = 0$).